# Need to specify TextBox style on each view in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, catel, fluent-ribbon

I'm developing a WPF application using Catel & Orchestra Framework as I did in past.

In this particular application, it seems that if I don't specify the style inside the UserControl's resouces it doesn't apply

So I've to do in each view

```
  <Grid.Resources>


            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
            </Style>
  <Grid.Resources>
```

And here's my Application.Xaml's resources

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <telerik:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter"></telerik:EnumToBooleanConverter>
    <telerik:InvertedBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanConverter"></telerik:InvertedBooleanConverter>
    <telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    <system:Double x:Key="Width">250</system:Double>
    <GridLength  x:Key="DefaultRowWidth">250</GridLength>
    <GridLength  x:Key="DefaultRowHeigth">40</GridLength>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadDatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The enums, static values and so on are correctly recognized and used, in the case of the TextBlock/CheckBoxes and so on, no. I'm also using the [FluentRibbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon) and Telerik as UI component (as I did in past).

Any suggestion?

Here's the layout without in user control's resource

[image]

and with it

[image]

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Do you have two styles applied to checkboxes etc.? Does it work inside the usercontrol? maybe give us a link to the full code of the usercontrol/app.xaml.

Comment: If I put the style inside the usercontrol, it works. The App.xaml code is all here... nothing more

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the `StyleHelper` which creates all the styles for you (based on naming convention, `Default[ControlName]Style` (e.g. `DefaultTextBlockStyle`). Orchestra does provide all of these styles out of the box, and you need to override them on the right layer to make sure they win.

You have a few options:

1. Specify your own version of `DefaultTextBlockStyle` and it should work.
2. Disable the StyleHelper / style forwarders
3. Override the style on a lower level (e.g. the user control level)